# Pasar de foreach a implementar [array_map, array_filter, array_recursive]

Tags: php, array, refactoring

Tengo el siguiente escenario, un `array`:

```php
        $array  = [
            [
                'char'  => ' ',
                'count' => 15,
            ],
            [
                'char'  => 'nombre',
                'count' => 25,
            ],
            [
                'char'  => '//Comentario',
                'count' => 30,
            ],
        ];
```

Pensaba recorrerlo de la siguiente forma:

```php
        $buffer = '';
        foreach ($array as $line_constructor) {
            $buffer .= str_pad($line_constructor['char'], $line_constructor['count'], " ");
        }
        return $buffer . PHP_EOL;
```

***Se puede implementar de una manera más moderna con `array_map`, `array_filter` o `array_recursive`?***

Comment: todas esas formas son validas, por lo que todo se reduce a lo que necesites

Comment: hola @Christian las etiquetas de refactoring la estoy usando ya que desconozco como implementarlas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que lo hagas usando dos funciones:

- [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php): que te permite *mapear* los valores en las cadenas que deseas en cada elemento de tu `array` original.
- [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php): que toma el `array` del paso anterior y produce la salida de una sola cadena.

Por ejemplo:

```php
<?php
$array = [
  [
    'char'  => ' ',
    'count' => 15,
  ],
  [
    'char'  => 'nombre',
    'count' => 25,
  ],
  [
    'char'  => '//Comentario',
    'count' => 30,
  ]
];

// función para realizar el mapeo.
function get_mapped($item) {
  return str_pad($item['char'], $item['count'], " ");
}

// función reductora
function get_reduced($acc, $curr) {
  $acc .= $curr;
  return $acc;
}

// array mapeado
$mapped_array = array_map("get_mapped", $array);

// resultado de la reducción
$reduced = array_reduce($mapped_array, "get_reduced");

// aquí añades el fin de linea.
$reduced .= PHP_EOL;
echo $reduced;
?>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Aquí tienes un [ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d53018a0ca58b5aedbf47d0c062793d23d5a459a) de cómo se ve la salida, excepto que he cambiado el carácter de *padding* por un asterisco.